# JAVA - Error while comparing Object items

Tags: java

I have the following code

```
set1.forEach( k -> {
   for (String s : set2) {
        if(s.split(";")[0].equals(k){
            //do something
        }
    }
...
```

but I have this error

```
k cannot be resolved to a variable
```

Is there a way to read this variable?

Thanks

Comment: Lambda expressions were introduced in JDK 8, probably you are using an earlier version.

Comment: WFM: https://ideone.com/LT5MKR can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: @Adit I'm currently using JDK 8

Answer (score 2):

You missed one paranthesis after k. You should have two closed paranthesis as below near equals

```
    Set<String> set1 = new HashSet<>();

    Set<String> set2 = new HashSet<>();

    set1.forEach((k)-> {
        for (String string : set2) {
            if(string.split(":")[0].equals(k)){
                //do something
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Solved. `if` statement was not closed. The error was about variable k, but the problem was a missing parenthesis

Comment: @Fab Yes, you missed paranthesis of if